Does "sweet dreams to me then" make sense?
Yesterday I was talking to a native English speaker online. It was getting pretty late, so I decided to go to bed. I was going to say, "Sweet dreams". But then I realized that we both lived in different time zones. So I said, "Sweet dreams to me then". I obviously meant it as a joke.
A couple of hours ago I logged on HiNative and asked people there, "Hey, does this phrase sound natural?"
They told me that "sweet dreams to me then" sounds weird.
So...
How do I make sure that everything I say sounds natural? Native English speakers don't like correcting my mistakes, even if I ask them for help. How do I improve my English skills then? And what's wrong with "sweet dreams to me then"? I hear native English speakers say weird things all the time! The people on Smosh sometimes say stuff, that I'm not sure even exists. Spencer once said, "Collect my pages" as a joke. How come he gets to make up weird expressions, but I can't?
How was I supposed to know that the phrase I used sounded unnatural? I watch a lot of videos on YouTube, but I can't possibly know every little English expression, can I?
Now that I think about it, don't people sometimes say, "Happy birthday to me"? I'm pretty sure I heard someone say it. What do birthdays have that dreams don't? Now you're all just being just dream-phobic.
And yes, I just used the word "dream-phobic". I did that because I once heard SatchOnSims say "blue-phobic". And I'm pretty sure that "blue-phobic" is not a real word.
God, why is English so weird?
If native English speakers can say "blue-phobic" and "Happy birthday to me", then why can't I say "Sweet dreams to me then" and "dream-phobic"? Is there a dictionary where I can look up all these weird expressions?

It's only 'weird' because we normally wish 'Sweet dreams' to someone else, not to ourselves. You know that, which is why it was a joke. It's nothing to do with English grammar.

Yes, it's completely fine.

By the way, English is not particularly weird in this way. Your language has about the same amount of expressions, particular ways of saying something, inconsistencies, rule that are broken (etc) as English. People tend to judge other languages differently from their own, because they have forgotten learning their native language.

As a joke in context, it's perfectly comprehensible. It's sort of a "subversion of expectations" that's common in humor. In your case, you use an idiomatic phrase, "sweet dreams", but then change it in an unexpected, yet still logical (from some point of view) way. Sometimes that flies over people's heads or they think it "doesn't seem right", which is entirely subjective.

It's a joke,  it is supposed to sound weird, if it didn't sound weird, it wouldn't be funny.
So don't worry about it.
More generally, the best way to improve is to make mistakes. Look at how kids learn to speak English.  They sound weird all the time.  Native speakers often sound weird too, it is called being creative.
Again, don't worry about it.  Being a bit weird is not weird.

I will mildly observe that 'weird' can mean, especially to young people, 'unfamiliar to me, or deemed odd or strange by my peer group'.
